# KeyError:"['class']" not found in axis

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, pyxll

I found a tutorial about decision tree algorithm using pyxll add-in for excel, and tried to execute. I get an error: KeyError:"['class']" not found in axis.

```
from pyxll import xl_func
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import os

@xl_func("float, int, int: object")
def ml_get_zoo_tree_2(train_size=0.75, max_depth=5, random_state=245245):
    # Load the zoo data
    dataset = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "zoo.csv"))

    # Drop the animal names since this is not a good feature to split the data on
    dataset = dataset.drop("animal_name", axis=1)

    # Split the data into a training and a testing set
    features = dataset.drop("class", axis=1)
    targets = dataset["class"]

    train_features, test_features, train_targets, test_targets = \
        train_test_split(features, targets, train_size=train_size, random_state=random_state)

    # Train the model
    tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=max_depth)
    tree = tree.fit(train_features, train_targets)

    # Add the feature names to the tree for use in predict function
    tree._feature_names = features.columns

    return tree
```

If i removed line 17 and 18 for class code, then i get error NameError: name 'features' is not defined, then when i removed feature i get error as target has to be defined.

Comment: Are you sure about the column name, it is "class"? Just print `dataset.columns` and see if the name matches.

Comment: There is no column class, and how to define feature and target to split dataset?

Comment: Just replace the "class" with the name of your target coulmn.

Comment: I dont have a target column in dataset

Comment: How can you apply decision tree if you don't have a dependent variable I.e. your target column?

Comment: Can you edit your question by printing the column names of your dataset? Also specify your feature columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the correct dataset to go with that tutorial. You can download it (and the code) from here https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-examples/tree/master/machine-learning.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, I first executed the command `print dataset.columns` to compare the column names.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_dataset.csv')
print(df.columns)
```

Upon inspection, I discovered a space after the `class` column name, which was not visible when checking the dataset. Removing the spaces next to the `class` column in the dataset rectified the error.